# What is the cause of the Kivy syntax error in the .run() minute?

Tags: python, kivy

I started using Kivy today.
When I tried to display a window by imitation, an error occurs at the very last KadaiApp().run() no matter how many times I try;;
Here is my code.
Sorry for the clumsiness.

main.py

```
lass KadaiWidget(Widget):
    source = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KadaiWidget).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass
#==============================================
Processing when a button is pressed in between.
#==============================================
class KadaiApp(App):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(KadaiApp,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title='Test'
    pass
    
    #def build(self):
        #return KadaiWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KadaiApp().run()
```

Kadai.kv

```
<KadaiWidget>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: "bg.png"
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    TextInput:
        id: text1
        size: 200, 30
        pos: 40, 340
        line_height: 1
        multiline: False
        hint_text: 'URL'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                id: button1
                source: .\tsuika.png
                pos: 325, 350
                on_pless: root.tsuika_btn_click(self)

            Button:
                id: start_button
                source: .\start.png
                pos: 195,600
                on_pless: root.start_btn_click(self)

            Button:
                id: stop_button
                source: .\stop.png
                pos: 340, 710
                on_pless: root.top_btn_click(self)

            Button:
                id: URL
                source: .\url.png
                pos: 160,350
```

When I do this, I get the following error;;

```
   KadaiApp().run()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (kadai.kv, line 24)
```

Well, as I write this`(kadai.kv, line 24)`I am fine, although I have a touch of anxiety.
I know this is a very silly question from everyone here, but I hope you will answer it;;

Comment: It would be helpful to emphasize what exactly is this line 24 which causing the SyntaxError, and what steps have you taken to fix it.

Comment: When you specify a `source:` in the `kv`, it must be a string. Try changing `source: .\url.png` to `source: ".\url.png"`.

Comment: I got beat up...
Everything was fine when I put the "" on...
My half day...
Thank you, brother.